# Downgrade to Android 9 on Google Chromecast with Google TV

Tags: downgrade

I have a Google Chromecast with Google TV running Android 10 and I need to downgrade to Android 9 as I'm integrating with Home Assistant and the sendevent command I want to use is blocked on Android 10 (SELinux policy).

Where can I find an Android 9 firmware image and how can I install this on my Google Chromecast with Google TV?